# Material navigation drawer header dimensions

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I'm trying to implement the latest style of navigation drawer according to the material design guidelines. I would like to use custom background picture for the header background. 
The problem is that I was not able to find any information about recommended picture size or aspect ratio for different pixel densities. 
I've downloaded some demo app which uses the only one picture for all densities and its dimensions are: 512x288. Would it be enough for all densities?
Thanks

Comment: Look at Google's official iosched app here: https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src

Comment: This may help you www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Thank Jared Burrows, but that app looks kinda outdated.
Arul Nadhan, I know this website. As You can see, there is no information about size of the section with profile pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I have read a post about Navigation drawer header dimensions and would like to share with you and for anyone in need. It's [here](https://medium.com/android-news/navigation-drawer-styling-under-material-design-f0767882e692#.a3b6gw12a) in depth which said at the end as below : (correct me if I understood wrong):

> The 320 dp on phones and 400 dp on tablets/desktop is the max width
>   standard for all Google apps in Material Design

I strongly suggest you to read whole post which will give you in depth understanding about navigation drawer dimensions.

Hope it helps.